# Font options on internal rich text fields

Tags: lightning, richtextarea

In Lightning on internal rich text fields, my users are able to adjust the font and font size.  However, as an admin I don't have those options.  This is not a browser issue as I can sit at my computer and not see the options when logged in as an admin.  However, when I login as a user I see the font and font size options.  Thoughts on what is going on?  I am guessing a rights issue, but I have no idea which one.

In Classic, I don't see the font/font size options at all on the rich content fields whether an administrator or regular user.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be related to this [Salesforce known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Skn7QAC).

It is scheduled to be fixed in Spring 20.